# Enable developer mode in Xiaomi Mi Home App

Tags: openhab, xiaomi-mi

I would like to use my [Xiaomi Gateway v2 **EU-Version**](https://www.amazon.de/Xiaomi-Control-Bewegungssensoren-Fensterkontakt-Drahtloser-wei%C3%9F/dp/B07KXN6S74) with [openHAB](https://www.openhab.org/addons/bindings/mihome/). In order to do that I need to enable the developer mode in [Xiaomi MI Home app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xiaomi.smarthome&hl=en). These are the full instructions from openHAB:

```
1.  Select your Gateway in the MiHome app
2.  Go to the "..." menu on the top right corner and click "About"
3.  Tap the version number "Plug-in version : 2.XX.X" at the bottom of the screen repeatedly until you enable developer mode
4.  You should now have 2 extra options listed: `wireless communication protocol` and `hub info`
5.  Choose `wireless communication protocol`
6.  Tap the toggle switch to enable WiFi functions. Note down the developer key (aka password), something like: 91bg8zfkf9vd6uw7
7.  Make sure you hit the OK button (to the right of the cancel button) to save your changes
```

I'm stuck at #2: `Go to the "..." menu on the top right corner and click "About"` - there is no *About* menu. I tried switching the **region** from Germany to China but with the same result.

How to enable the developer mode in Xiaomi Mi Home App? Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this forum](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/mi-home-app-developer-mode/3740/8), in the newest version you are :

> no longer able to activate the Dev Mode

However you can :

> replace the Xiaomi Hub with a CC2531 USB sniffer that enables you to communicate directly via Zigbee with your Xiaomi sensors.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Would it be possible to use an older version of the Xiaomi Mi Home Android app to activate the Dev Mode?

Comment: I assume so if you can find a download

Comment: I tried it with multiple old versions of the app, didn't work for me. (if anybody else want to give it a shot: old Mi Home versions are available on apkmirror.com)

Comment: remember if using apkmirror.com you will need to be disable androids only download from play store settings.

Answer (score 0):

On my manual there is a sticker with the code also on the HUB
But the code on the manual (HUB) is with 8 numbers 4 x 4
You have to put it into HA as xxx-xx-xxx and that works for  me !